# javascript is not acting on HTML content loaded via jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I am trying to create a form filled with ajax requests, but my javascript is not acting on the HTML that i loaded with the ajax call to my server.

```
---template----
<form id="my_form" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
                                <fieldset>
                                <legend>Book Tickets</legend>
                        <div>
            <label for="state">Theatre:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <select id="state" class="pure-input-1-2">
                {% for mul in film.multiplexes.all %}
                <option id="op{{ forloop.counter }}" title="{{ mul.name }}">{{ mul.name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <br>

     <div id="date-input">
     </div>
    <br>
    <div>
         <input type="radio" name="time" value="morning" checked> 10:00 &nbsp;&nbsp;
         <input type="radio" name="time" value="evening"> 1:00 &nbsp;&nbsp;
         <input type="radio" name="time" value="night"> 6:00 
    </div>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Book Ticket">
</fieldset>
```

the html is loading just fine inside div with id date-input
this is my views.py

```
----views.py---
def bookdate(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    mov = request.POST.get('mov')
    multiplex = request.POST.get('multiplex')
    movie = Movies.objects.get(title = mov)
    for mult in movie.multiplexes.all():
        try:
            if mult.name == multiplex:
                date = mult.date.all()
                return render(request, 'jtc/bookdate.html', {'dates':date})
        except:
            pass
return render(request, 'jtc/bookdate.html',{})
```

This is my script that is acting on my current page to load radio buttons for the selected dropdown

```
-------template-------
<script>
//for date
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#state").on('change', function(){
                console.log($(this).find("option:selected").prop("title"));
                $.ajaxSetup({cache:'true'});
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'bookdate' %}",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                            'multiplex' : $(this).find("option:selected").prop("title"),
                            'mov': $("#mymovie").text(),
                            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': getCookie('csrftoken')
                        },
                    success: function(data){
                        document.getElementById("date-input").innerHTML=data;
                    },
                    failure: function(){
                        alert("SERVER ERROR Conatct admin");
                    }
                    });
                });
            });
</script>
```

this is how i am loading content inside the div with id #date-input
Now what i want is to get further time according to which date i select but the script is not working on this new loaded html
My script for action on newly loaded html

```
----template----
<script>
//for time
        $('#date-input').on('click', '#state', function(){
            $('#my_form input').on('change',function(){
                console.log($('input[name=date]:checked', '#form_date').val());
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'booktime' %}",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {},
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data);    
                    },
                    failure: function(){
                        alert("Contact admin server error");
                    }
                });
                });
            });
</script>
```

help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand python, but you will need to run your JS after new HTML nodes have been loaded through AJAX.

Just append a simple `<script>` element at the end of your AJAX content, so that it runs run the javascript again.

Comment: Thanks this was neat . I just have to write my script inside success function of ajax and its all working fine

Comment: Sorry man my mistake this isn't working i provided with a different id and thought it was working but the problem sttill lies @Nisarg

Comment: Can you update the question to show what you are doing now?

Comment: I am not doing any thing different i'm still stuck at the part that "**How to apply jquery on the newly loaded html from ajax **

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the newly loaded Html and what does the new html look like?